# Проблема с обращением к Скрипту Button

Tags: c#, unity3d

Здравствуйте , есть лист объектов, содержащий весь список уровней, который присутствует к игре. Я прохожу по этому списку и включаю картинки на тех уровнях, которые разблокированы. Но вот не задача , кнопка до сих пор продолжает работать.
И я пытаюсь обратиться к компоненту Button, который лежит на самом игровом объекте, но у меня ни как не получается это сделать.
[image: bt - экземпляр класса Button]

PS: bt - экземпляр класса Button. UnityEngine.UI подключен , но отображается так, будто бы не используется в данном коде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создал сейчас проект, сделал примерно такой же код, как и у вас, пишу:

```
var btn = go.GetComponent<Button>();
```

Мне студия подключает следующее:

```
using UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements;
```

Работаю дальше, `interactable` не находит. Подключаю `using UnityEngine.UI;` и вижу, что у меня конфликт, `Button` оказывается есть и в `UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements` и в `UnityEngine.UI`.

Удаляю `using UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements;` и вуаля, кнопка поддерживает `interactable`. Если вам по какой то причине не хочется удалять эту строку, то можно явно попробовать указать, то есть: `var btn = go.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Button>();`

Comment: Я  не использую эту директиву в своем коде, у меня стадартные UnityEngine   , System.Collections.Generic ,  UnityEngine.SceneManagement И на этом все

Comment: Наведите на Button в строке `go.GetComponent<Button>();` и посмотрите от куда она идет. Должно быть так: https://i.imgur.com/NGpRar4.png

Comment: Спасибо, моя глупость меня и погубила. В области видимости был создан публичный одноименный класс Button  и получалось так ,что при обращении к классу Button вызывался мой класс, спасибо большое ,что помогли докопаться до истины.

Comment: @ba3uk На здоровье. Удачи в программирование ! ;-)